# Linux Network Managing Api

Tags: php, networking, centos, erp

I have an ERP web application ,and 
I want to give the application admin the ability to manage network settings of my server operating system from my application.

What are the main network issues which I have to take care about them ?

and Are there any APIs to do that  ?

Hint:
My application is written with **php**, and my server os is **CentOS**.

Comment: what's "network stuffs" (and why would you want application admin to handle that)?

Comment: I mean 'network settings' such as (bonding interfaces,DHCP managing ..) . And I want to make a layer between Admin and OS .

Comment: until someone answers, perhaps you might consider [webmin](http://www.webmin.com/)?